# Spring's ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> breaks the @CrossOrigin

Tags: spring, spring-security, cors

So I have this server Spring app with @CrossOrigin annotations over controllers (for my React client). The issue is that when I implement this:

```
@Component
public class LoginListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {
    @Autowired
    RealtimeAlertsThreadFactory alertsFactory;

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
    UserDetails ud = (UserDetails) event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    
    alertsFactory.createAlerts(ud.getUsername());
  }
}
```

the CORS starts blocking every request. Anyone knows why is that?

Answer (score -1):

Haha, just needed to add a @CrossOrigin to the Listener itself :)